# vim find command: how to list all matched files

Tags: file, vim, find

The :find command of vim just matches only one file. If more files are matched, it gives message "Too many file names" . 
Is there any command of vim which can find files by using wildcards or regular expression, and allow user to navigate between these files matched?

Comment: Internal command is better, not plugins.

Comment: You can get a list of the files with the `globpath()` function. To list all python files in the current working directory: `:echo globpath(".", "*.py")` You can then display that list and either let the user be more specific, or if you're being fancy then let them pick a number to choose which file. Another thing to look into is `browse confirm e` which is a file browser; Not too familiar with it but there might be something like what you're after somewhere near it.

Comment: Is there any convenient and simple command?

Comment: Not that I know of; It's not really the kind of thing that I personally would want to do from within vim. You could write something in vimscript, but that seems more like a shell's job to me. I would write an external script or program to do this, then call it from vim if I wanted something like that.

Comment: Well I just googled it. Try typing `:e ` (`e` and a space) and then hitting control+d. It will list all files in the current directory. Then type in a shell glob (`*.py` for instance). It will list all `.py` files. Type in a whole filename and it will open it up.

Comment: :e will also give message "too many file names" .  :next args can record files matched, and single :next without args to open next file. But I don't know how to display the file list to allow me to select.

Comment: Hit the tab key to pop up a list of possibilities, instead of enter. Then type more specific filenames to winnow down the list. Once there is only one file, hit enter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You seem to be confusing Vim's command-line completion and the `:find` command itself.

`:find` only accepts one single filename (or something that resolves to a single filename) as argument but the command-line completion that lets you complete that single argument allows you to go through *all* the files in your `path` matching your current pattern.

That confusion makes what you actually want non-obvious:

- do you want `:find` to open for editing *every* file matching your pattern?
- or do you want a list of matches from which to choose from?

The former is impossible by design but you can use the `:new` command (`:help :new`):

```
:new *.foo
```

The latter is possible, of course. For that, you'll need to set at least a few options in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:full
```

See `:help wildmode` for how to customize the wildmenu's behavior. Those settings will of course work for other commands: `:edit`, `:split`, `:buffer`…

A few suggestions:

```
set path+=**
```

lets Vim find files recursively under the other directories in `path`. **Note that `**` is *very* greedy, which means that Vim will really look everywhere under those directories, which can be *very* expensive and slow (think `node_modules`). As with lots of things in Vim, the `path` value should be context-dependant**.

```
set wildignorecase
```

tells Vim to ignore case for completion: `:find foo` will match `foo.txt` and `Foo.txt`.

```
set wildignore=*.foo,*.bar
```

tells Vim to ignore those files (it can be directories) when doing completion.

Finally, here are a bunch of mappings that make my life (in Vim) so easy:

```
" regex completion instead of whole word completion
nnoremap <leader>f :find *
" restrict the matching to files under the directory
" of the current file, recursively
nnoremap <leader>F :find <C-R>=expand('%:p:h').'/**/*'<CR>

" same as the two above but opens the file in an horizontal window
nnoremap <leader>s :sfind *
nnoremap <leader>S :sfind <C-R>=expand('%:p:h').'/**/*'<CR>

" same as the two above but with a vertical window
nnoremap <leader>v :vert sfind *
nnoremap <leader>V :vert sfind <C-R>=expand('%:p:h').'/**/*'<CR>
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: :find]

Comment: In case it wasn't clear...with the suggested 'wildmode' and 'wildmenu' settings, you can now just hit `<Tab>` instead of `<Enter>` to cycle through a list of all matches to an incomplete `:find` command.

Answer (score 3):

The `findfile` function can return a list, so it's just a matter of calling that in a custom command.

Here's a quick one-liner that will show the list of results from the path and prompt for which one you want ("FF" == Find File):

```
command! -nargs=1 FF let i=1|let mm=findfile(<q-args>, '', -1)|for f in mm| echo i.':'.f|let i+=1 |endfor|let choice=input('FF: ')|exec 'e ' . mm[choice-1]
```

Example:

```
:FF socket.h
1:/usr/include/bits/socket.h
2:/usr/include/asm/socket.h
3:/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h
4:/usr/include/linux/socket.h
5:/usr/include/sys/socket.h
FF:
```

Enter the number of the one you want, and hit ENTER. Or just hit ENTER to get the last one.

Comment: super useful! I wish this was a built in

Answer (score 1):

I use the following self-defined command to find all todo items in the *.g files, and list them in a quickfix window. Then I can jump among them by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the quickfix window.

```
command! Td noautocmd vimgrep /TODO\|FIXME/j *.g | cw
```